# Pygame - " display.set_mode() " creates a smaller window, than requested ( Surfaces are outside of the window )

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I´m trying to draw a ship on the bottom-right of the screen, but it´s not appearing on the window! Coordinates seem to be off on X, Y by approximately 50 points. No matter what kind of resolution is set through `pygame.display.set_mode()`, the window is always smaller than the defined dimensions ( by 50 ).

External FULL HD screen is connected to the laptop through HDMI, but disconnecting it had no effect. Using Windows 10, Python 3.6.2 and Pygame 1.9.3.

[Using "centerx", "bottom" to display the ship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxlFu.png)

[Same as above, but substracting both "centerx" and "bottom" by 50.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7tlb.png)

```
import sys
import pygame


def main():
    #Initialize the screen.
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( 1024, 768 ) )

    screen_rect = screen.get_rect() 

    bg_color = ( 235, 235, 235 )

    # Load the ship surface, get its rect.
    ship_image = pygame.image.load( "images/ship.bmp" ) 
    ship_rect = ship_image.get_rect()

    # TRYING TO POSITION THE SHIP TO THE BOTTOM-RIGHT OF THE SCREEN.
    screen_bottom_right = screen_rect.centerx, screen_rect.bottom

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if ( event == "QUIT" ):
                sys.exit()


        # Redraw the screen.
        screen.fill( bg_color )
        # Blit the ship´s image.
        screen.blit( ship_image, ( screen_bottom_right ) )

        pygame.display.flip()
main()
```

Tried searching for answers, but none of them had worked / explicitly mentioned this issue. Tutorials, which used the code didn´t substract the X/Y coordinates to obtain exactly positioned image. "0, 0" as rect drawing position works flawlessly. The bottom-right suffers from the above-mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame blits the image so that its top left corner is positioned at the coordinates that you passed. So by passing the screen bottom as the y-coord you're telling pygame to draw the ship below the screen. To fix this you can assign the `bottomright` attribute of the `screen_rect` to the `bottomright` of the `ship_rect` and then just blit the image at the `ship_rect`.

```
import sys
import pygame


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect() 

    bg_color = (235, 235, 235)

    ship_image = pygame.Surface((40, 50))
    ship_image.fill((20, 10, 100))
    ship_rect = ship_image.get_rect()
    ship_rect.bottomright = screen_rect.bottomright

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        screen.blit(ship_image, ship_rect)

        pygame.display.flip()

main()
```

[`pygame.Rect`s](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) have a lot of other attributes that you can use as well, but keep in mind that only the `topleft` coords are used as the blit position:

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
size, width, height
w,h
```